# QBChatMessage+QBDateDivider.h: Quickblox/Quickblox.h file not found

Tags: quickblox

I've been trying to integrate QMChatViewController into my project (manually, not with CocoaPods), but no matter what I try, I keep getting the following error:

*QBChatMessage+QBDateDivider.h:

'Quickblox/Quickblox.h' file not found*

I assume if my project is pure Swift and I'm not using CocoaPods, I don't need a bridging header, right?

Comment: I don't have a Prefix.pch file, so I wonder if this could be related to the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just discovered the issue. When I dragged and dropped Quickblox.framework into the project, I didn't check Destination: Copy Items if Needed.